# Element under its fixed parent using `z-index` in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit, z-index

I want an element (`div`) to be layered under its fixed parent (`header`):

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  
  background-color: #ccc;
}
header > div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
  
  transform: translateY(50%);
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
  </div>
</header>
```

This works in Firefox but not in Chrome. To fix it you need to do this:

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
header > div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  background-color: #ccc;
}
header > div > div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: -1;

  transform: translateY(50%);
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

But this sucks! **Who is wrong according to the specification Firefox or Chrome? And is there a better approach to get this done across browsers?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome: can't position one absolute div over another when the parent is fixed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798669/chrome-cant-position-one-absolute-div-over-another-when-the-parent-is-fixed)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}
header > div {
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  background-color: #aaa;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <div></div>
</header>
```

Seems like I have misunderstand your question. Anyway the answer is chrome is correct. I think the better solution for do this is, using same level  two DIVs(If possible).

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}
header .header-inner {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

header .under-layer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  background-color: #aaa;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-inner"></div>
  <div class="under-layer"></div>
</header>
```

Comment: I think you got me wrong: `overflow: hidden` hides the element whenever it's (partially) outside of its parent. But I want it exactly like the examples I've posted. So this answer might be only right about chrome; could you refer to the standard therefore?

Answer (score 0):

When an element has position: a new context is created, which means that the `div` 
 is relative to the `window` context. So your div can not be z-indexly placed regarding to the `header`.

You will have to use a workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to "position fix" your header, you can wrap it in a div :

```
<div class="test">
<header>
  <div>
  </div>
</header>
</div>
```

Apply `position: fixed;` to this div instead. This will create a [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) for the div.

```
.test {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

You can then apply `z-index: -1;` to `header > div` as it will share the [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) of `div.test` with its parent (header).

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

header > div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: -1;

  transform: translateY(50%);
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```css
.test {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

header>div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <header>
    <div>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```